# Docker user namespace isolation: permission denied with bind mount

Tags: linux, docker, permissions, file-permissions, linux-namespaces

I enabled user namespace isolation as depicted in [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Docker#User_namespace_isolation) and on [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/).

However, when I try to use a bind mount:

```
# this is fish shell
$ docker run --rm -it -v (pwd)/bmount/:/bmount alpine sh
```

I get:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime
> create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process
> caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused:
> rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "xxxx/bmount" to rootfs at "/bmount"
> caused: stat xxxx/bmount: permission denied: unknown.

I managed to get regular docker volume to work without issue. As far as I'm understanding this setup, bind mount should be working given the container has rights on the folder, right?

### Here is some more details:

I created a `dockremap` user and group, both having an UID/GID of 200000
Here is the content of `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`

> dockremap:200000:65536

> dockremap:200000:65536

And docker is configured to use user namespace isolation, here is the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

> {   "userns-remap": "dockremap" }

I made sure the bmount folder I'm trying to bind mount is chown to `dockremap`

> drwxr-xr-x  2 dockremap dockremap 4,0K 24 juin  13:08 bmount

docker info gives this:

> Client: Context:    default Debug Mode: false Plugins:   app: Docker
> App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)   buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker
> Inc., v0.5.1-tp-docker)
>
> Server: Containers: 0   Running: 0   Paused: 0   Stopped: 0 Images: 2
> Server Version: 20.10.7 Storage Driver: overlay2   Backing Filesystem:
> extfs   Supports d_type: true   Native Overlay Diff: false
> userxattr: false Logging Driver: json-file Cgroup Driver: systemd
> Cgroup Version: 2 Plugins:   Volume: local   Network: bridge host
> ipvlan macvlan null overlay   Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf
> journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog Swarm: inactive
> Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
> Default Runtime: runc Init Binary: docker-init containerd version:
> 36cc874494a56a253cd181a1a685b44b58a2e34a.m runc version:
> b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7 init version: de40ad0
> Security Options:   seccomp    Profile: default   userns   cgroupns
> Kernel Version: 5.12.11-arch1-1 Operating System: Arch Linux OSType:
> linux Architecture: x86_64 CPUs: 2 Total Memory: 3.735GiB Name:
> CRIQUET ID:
> AT7Q:T3HO:HBFF:H7AM:XABE:KY4B:AQ2H:POBZ:YUE3:XGOT:4ROB:SDUX Docker
> Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/200000.200000 Debug Mode: false Registry:
> https://index.docker.io/v1/ Labels: Experimental: false Insecure
> Registries:
> 127.0.0.0/8 Live Restore Enabled: false

$ uname -a

> Linux CRIQUET 5.12.11-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 16 Jun 2021 15:25:28
> +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Same here. If I remove namespace isolation, then it works. I guess it's too isolated...

Comment: I guess this line is relevant: "User namespaces are an advanced feature and require coordination with other capabilities. For example, if volumes are mounted from the host, file ownership must be pre-arranged need read or write access to the volume contents."
On the bottom of https://www.typeerror.org/docs/docker~19/engine/security/userns-remap/index